# Empty citeindex using biblatex DeclareCiteCommand

Tags: biblatex, xetex, oldstylenums, liningnums

I want to prevent biblatex using OldStyle figures for supercite indices.

MWE:

```
% !TEX engine=xelatex
\documentclass{scrreprt}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont
     [ BoldFont       = texgyrepagella-bold.otf ,
       ItalicFont     = texgyrepagella-italic.otf ,
       BoldItalicFont = texgyrepagella-bolditalic.otf,
       Numbers = OldStyle ]
     {texgyrepagella-regular.otf}
 \linespread{1.05}

\newfontfamily\biblatexfont{texgyrepagella-regular.otf}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{mwe.bib}
  @book{book_sze,
    title = {Physics of Semiconductor Devices},
    author = {Sze, S.M.},
    date = {1969},
    publisher = {{WILEY-INTERSCIENCE}},
    location = {{Bell Telephone Laboratories, Incorporated Murray Hill, New Jersey}},
  }
\end{filecontents}


\usepackage{biblatex}
\addbibresource{mwe.bib}

\DeclareCiteCommand{\supercite}[\mkbibsuperscript]
  {}{}{\biblatexfont\usebibmacro{citeindex}}
  {\supercitedelim}{}

\begin{document}
  Test sentence\supercite{book_sze} 1234567
\end{document}
```

I don't get any citeindex, the entry is just empty. I'm using XeLaTeX. Is it the wrong bibmacro? But if so, where can I find a list with valid bibmacros?

Comment: `citeindex` sends the author name and title to the index (with `\index`), but your document has no setup for an index, so that macro won't do anything useful for you. The original definition of `\supercite` for your setup can be found in `numeric.cbx`: https://github.com/plk/biblatex/blob/2ddd2836927d08ac600c8fa3af1897417548ac05/tex/latex/biblatex/cbx/numeric.cbx#L98-L108. Basically you are missing the crucial bit `\usebibmacro{cite}` in your definition.

Comment: I am not aware of an exhaustive list of available bibmacros, but you should be able to find everything you need in `biblatex.def`, `standard.bbx` as well as `<style>.bbx`, `<style>.cbx` (and files loaded by those style files). (I usually grep the complete `biblatex` folder if I look for a definition.)

Comment: Thanks, that was the missing bit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`citeindex` sends the author name and title to the index (with `\index`), but your document has no setup for an index, so that macro won't do anything useful for you. You can find its definition in [`biblatex.def` (ll. 2305-2309 in v3.14)](https://github.com/plk/biblatex/blob/2ddd2836927d08ac600c8fa3af1897417548ac05/tex/latex/biblatex/biblatex.def#L2305-L2309).

The original definition of `\supercite` in your setup (if you don't pass any style options to `biblatex` that is equivalent to `style=numeric,`) can be found in [`numeric.cbx` (ll. 98-108 in v3.14)](https://github.com/plk/biblatex/blob/2ddd2836927d08ac600c8fa3af1897417548ac05/tex/latex/biblatex/cbx/numeric.cbx#L98-L108)

```
\DeclareCiteCommand{\supercite}[\mkbibsuperscript]
  {\iffieldundef{prenote}
     {}
     {\BibliographyWarning{Ignoring prenote argument}}%
   \iffieldundef{postnote}
     {}
     {\BibliographyWarning{Ignoring postnote argument}}}
  {\usebibmacro{citeindex}%
   \usebibmacro{cite}}
  {\supercitedelim}
  {}
```

If you compare that with the definition in the MWE you see that the MWE is missing the checks and warnings for pre- and postnote and more crucially, the MWE is missing

```
\usebibmacro{cite}
```

The bibmacro `cite` is responsible for printing the actual citation label in the `numeric` style (and most other styles), so that explains why you don't see anything if you leave it out.

I'd probably define your `\supercite` as follows

```
\newrobustcmd{\mkbibsuperscriptoldstyle}[1]{\mkbibsuperscript{{\biblatexfont#1}}}

\DeclareCiteCommand{\supercite}[\mkbibsuperscriptoldstyle]
  {\iffieldundef{prenote}
     {}
     {\BibliographyWarning{Ignoring prenote argument}}%
   \iffieldundef{postnote}
     {}
     {\BibliographyWarning{Ignoring postnote argument}}}
  {\usebibmacro{citeindex}%
   \usebibmacro{cite}}
  {\supercitedelim}
  {}
```

(Technically speaking the double braces in `\mkbibsuperscript{{\biblatexfont#1}}` aren't necessary because `\mkbibsuperscript` already has an explicit group that would prevent the font change from leaking out, but I don't know if you want to rely on that implementation detail.)

---

There is no list of all defined bibmacros, but this list alone would probably be not that useful anyway as you would need to know the actual definitions of the bibmacros to make sense of things. You should be able to find everything you need to know in

- [`biblatex.def`](https://github.com/plk/biblatex/blob/master/tex/latex/biblatex/biblatex.def) (basic bibmacro and format definitions, always loaded by `biblatex`)
- [`standard.bbx`](https://github.com/plk/biblatex/blob/master/tex/latex/biblatex/bbx/standard.bbx) (defines the bibliography drivers and more complex bibmacros used by all `biblatex` standard styles and many contributed styles; not all contributed styles load this file, but most do)
- `<bibstyle>.bbx` and `<citestyle>.cbx` where `<bibstyle>` and `<citestyle>` are the name of the bibliography and citation style you use. Note that these files may load other styles via `\RequireBibliographyStyle` and `\RequireCitationStyle` or other methods.

I usually just grep the whole `biblatex` directory (https://github.com/plk/biblatex/tree/master/tex/latex/biblatex) when I'm looking for a definition.